# Changing UserAccount Name is not working Compeletly

Tags: windows-7, command-line

You can change your user account name by using the command below:

```
wmic UserAccount where Name="OLDName" call Rename Name="NEWName"
```

Also You can use VBScripts To do this job, But there is a problem, When I change user account using this way, the old name is still showing on my account, but If I run "net user" command I can not see any account with my old name.

Where is the problem? Listing Accounts will show that the name is changed, but in windows from start menu I'm still seeing old account name.

Answer (score 1):

Renaming accounts is difficult in Windows.

If you want every last aspect of the account to be renamed, you're better off creating a new user with the proper name, transferring files and settings, then removing the old username.

The reason is that when you create a user (for example. `Owner`), that user gets its own Security Objects, file system objects (C:\Users\Owner, for example), and files will rely on certain locations. If you rename a system folder (i.e. `C:\Windows` to `C:\Win7`), programs and shortcuts will cease to work! There are too many internals that are relying on your account name for a FULL rename to work.

For small cosmetic changes (i.e. `Wil` to `Will`), if you can live with just the look, it's fine to rename the account. The files will stay pointing to a user called `Wil`, but you'll know who that is.

If you want the cosmetic change (i.e. `Canadian Luke` -> `Luke Skywalker`), you can execute (as the user or an Administrator) the following command:

```
NET USER canadianluke /FULLNAME:"Luke Skywalker"
```

Comment: The Problem is that You can changing account name by your hand via start menu AND It will work like a charm, but using command propmt or scripts to change the name will cause a none complete changing, which is not applied in start menu :(

Comment: That's just one part of it though. There is so much under the hood that it's not worthwhile must times

Comment: It seems the command prompt will only change the name, but there is a full name beside the name.

Comment: Exactly! But with so many places that Windows or applications grab your name from, there would be too many steps and locations to change

Comment: So is'nt there any scripting way to change account fullname?

Comment: Just the full name? Sure! I'll update my answer